# When I connect my TV to my laptop via HDMI, the TV is not detected until I try to change my background or run xrandr

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, tv

When I connect my TV's HDMI input to my laptop's  HDMI-out port, the TV is not detected.

The HDMI icon on the TV input menu is greyed out but I am strangely still able to select it.  When I select the HDMI input on the TV, the TV screen is blank.

However, after some fiddling, I discovered that, when I try to change the PC's screen background, the desktop background suddenly appears on my TV and I can drag an app (such as a video player) to the TV's region. Once this happens, I just cancel the screen background change.

Also, after plugging the TV into my HDMI out port, if I open a terminal and run xrandr, the TV picks up the signal.  If I unplug and plug the HDMI, the TV still picks up the signal.  If I unplug the HDMI, run xrandr and plug in again, the TV stops picking up the signal.

When I unplug my TV HDMI cable, the PC stays awake even when I close the lid (and gets rather warm).  I have to fiddle with the screen background or run xrandr again to make any apps in the other monitor come back to the PC background and allow my pc to suspend when closing the lid.

This is all rather awkward and unintuitive.  How do I get my TV to be automatically detected as present or absent without having to fiddle with terminal commands or desktop settings?  What is wrong with the comms between the TV and the notebook PC?

TV Make: LG
TV Model: 37LD450

PC: System 76 Kudu Professional Notebook (2014)
OS: Ubuntu 18.04LTS
$ uname -srvmpio
Linux 5.3.0-7642-generic #34~1584407623~18.04~36777b2~dev-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 17 22:02:13  x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I had a bad cable.  I had thought I tried another cable but I have now found a good cable.  I would atrribute this problem to what is commonly called "finger trouble".